# Javascript accordion animation

Tags: javascript, animation

I am a beginner at javascript, and I got a code off of a site for an accordion and I would like to change the way the slider opens to a basic slide versus the animation it is given. I have three javascript files so I am unsure how where to change it, but the code in the head is

```
function init(){
var stretchers = document.getElementsByClassName('stretcher');
var toggles = document.getElementsByClassName('display');
var myAccordion = new fx.Accordion(
    toggles, stretchers, {opacity: true, height: true, width: true, duration: 400, transition: fx.sineInOut});
//hash functions
var found = false;
toggles.each(function(h3, i){
    var div = Element.find(h3, 'nextSibling');
        if (window.location.href.indexOf(h3.title) > 0) {
            myAccordion.showThisHideOpen(div);
            found = true;
        }
    });
if (!found) myAccordion.showThisHideOpen(stretchers[0]);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to change parameter opacity to false and see if the result is really what you expect.

Comment: This is not an answer and would be better suited as a comment.